# query fails on select in values

Tags: mysql

I am inserting records from one table to other where the status is lead. Now sincce the number of columns are different in both tables I have to use the field names. However its failing. Not sure where the cause is

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO Table1(
         lead_id,
    phone_number,
           title, 
           first_name, 
           middle_initial, 
           last_name, 
           address1, 
           address2, 
           address3, 
           city, 
           state, 
         postal_code, 
         gender, 
         date_of_birth, 
         alt_phone, 
         email,
         comments, 
         question_id, 
         answer_ques,
          situation_id, 
          best_time_contact, 
          specific_datetime, 
          specific_datetime_at, 
          leadcreated_by, 
          leadcreated_by_on,
           leadcreated_by_at, 
          transfer_by, 
          product_id,
      insertDTS    
          )
       SELECT 
        lead_id,
        phone_number,
        title, 
        first_name, 
           middle_initial, 
           last_name, 
           address1, 
           address2, 
           address3, 
           city, 
           state, 
         postal_code, 
         gender, 
         date_of_birth, 
         alt_phone, 
         email,
         comments, 
         question_id, 
         answer_ques,
          situation_id, 
          best_time_contact, 
          specific_datetime, 
          specific_datetime_at, 
          leadcreated_by, 
          leadcreated_by_on,
           leadcreated_by_at, 
          transfer_by, 
          product_id,
      insertDTS    

FROM TABLE2
WHERE TABLE2.status = 'LEAD'
```

This will work..no need for values
---thanks

Comment: Great. I was delayed in answering the same ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per my knowledge of mySql, you can not use VALUES and SELECT in the same insert statement. Try removing VALUES from the statement.
MySQL documentation shows the separate syntax for insert...values, insert...set and insert...select statements.

Answer (score 2):

```
     insert into test2(col1, col2) select col1, col2 from test1
```